# Suppress error message from bash loop

Tags: bash, debian

I've got the following line in my bash script:

```
for i in $(find ./TTDD* -type f)
    do
```

It works when there's files in the directory, but when it's empty I get the following:

```
find ... No such file or directory
```

How can I suppress that exact error message, as I'm logging output and doesn't care about that specific error message.

Comment: Are there a large number of directories *other* than ones that match `TTDD*` in the current directory?

Comment: If those are the only possible contents of the current directory then just drop that glob entirely and use `find .`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that globs that don't have any matches expand to themselves, and since there's no file named `TTDD*`, you get this error.

You can rewrite it in different ways. The most straight forward is:

```
find . -path './TTDD*' -type f
```

This will show the same files.

If there are other directories in the current dir, it will waste some time going through their files even if they'll never match. If required, you can short-circuit such directories with a less readable `find . -path . -o -not -path './TTDD*' -prune -o -type f -print`.

---

NB: iterating over these files with a `for` loops will break for files with spaces and various other special characters. You can combine this with anubhava's answer to safely read all filenames while also not suppressing all of `find`'s other potentially useful error messages.

```
while IFS= read -rd '' f; do
   printf "Processing [%s]\n" "$f"
done <  <(find . -path './TTDD*' -type f -print0 2>/dev/null)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about you use "-exec"?

This way you can redirect all results of your find command to the input of some other command, e.g., let's say that I want to find all the files within a given folder that are owned by the root user and I want to change the ownership of these files, here is the code:

```
find ${DataFS}/Data -user root -exec chown someuser:someuser {} \;
```

The approach you are using is similar to

```
find ${DataFS}/Data -user root -print0 | xargs -0 chown someuser:someuser
```

Which is not ideal because it will fail in case it can't find any files (i.e., if it prints an empty string), i.e., chown: missing operand after `someuser:someuser'

Comment: The `-r` flag to `xargs` covers the "no input" case.

Comment: Thanks :) that's good to know ..but "-exec" still seems like the best option, even for code readability

Comment: With `-exec +` yes. With `-exec \;` where you might have 0, 1, or 100000 files notsomuch.